# How can I insert data to Hbase from Kafka using Spark Streaming in a more efficient way?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, hbase, spark-streaming, apache-kafka-connect

I try to create Kafka Data Ingestion into HBase via PySpark. At the moment I try to insert data from Kafka to Hbase using HappyBase however it is very slow. I think that bulk loading also using HappyBase will not improve performance significantly. Below is the current source code. I need to achieve highest possible performance. Do you have any ideas? Maybe `saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset` or or any other solution?

```
def SaveToHBase(rdd):
    print("=====Pull from Stream=====")
    if not rdd.isEmpty():

        print(len(rdd.collect()))
        print(datetime.now())
        for line in rdd.collect():
            ctable.put((line.log_id), { \
            b'log:content': (line.log)})


kds = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, topic, k_params, fromOffsets=None)

parsed = kds.filter(lambda x: x != None and len(x) > 0 )
parsed = parsed.map(lambda x: x[1])
parsed = parsed.map(lambda rec: rec.split(","))
parsed = parsed.filter(lambda x: x != None and len(x) == 2 )
parsed = parsed.map(lambda data:Row(log_id=getValue(str,data[0]), \
        log=getValue(str,data[1])))

parsed.foreachRDD(SaveToHBase)
```

Comment: A more efficient pattern would probably be around Kafka Connect. I can submit an answer for that, if it would be useful? Or are you set on using PySpark?

Comment: @RobinMoffatt I would be grateful. I don't have to use PySpark, I just want to achieve the highest possible performance of streaming and inserting data to HBase.

Comment: @RobinMoffatt Are you going to add an answer? Is it possible to use Kafka Connect with `Hbase 2.0.2` and `Hadoop 2.8.4`? I don't have Confluent.

Answer (score 0):

A generally good tool to use for getting data between Kafka and external sources & targets is Kafka Connect.

Kafka Connect is part of Apache Kafka, and provides scalable streaming integration, requiring just a configuration file to implement. There are lots of pre-built connectors, and you can write your own too if you want. You can run Kafka Connect on a single machine, or clustered for resilience and throughput. It runs separately from your Kafka brokers.

If you want to process the data prior to landing it to a target, you would do that with a stream processing technology (Spark Streaming, Kafka Streams, KSQL, etc) and write the results to a Kafka topic. That Kafka topic then serves as the source for Kafka Connect to write to the target data store (in your case, HBase).

You can find a Kafka Connect connector for HBase here: https://www.confluent.io/connector/kafka-connect-hbase-sink/

Comment: Is it possible to use this Kafka Connect without confluent?

Comment: Yes, Kafka Connect is part of Apache Kafka. You can get connectors through Confluent Hub but also direct from source (e.g. this one is on github here https://github.com/nishutayal/kafka-connect-hbase)

Comment: What way would you recommend me to achieve highest possible performance with stack that I am using currently `Hbase 2.0.2`, `Hadoop 2.8.4` and `Kafka`?

Comment: If Kafka is part of your stack, then so is Kafka Connect.

Comment: Can I use github.com/nishutayal/kafka-connect-hbase for free? I see that this is under Apache License however there is written in deployment section to download Confluent and I am not sure whether I can use all needed tools to stream data from Kafka to Hbase?

Comment: The instructions mention Confluent just because that's an easy way to run Apache Kafka. But you can use Kafka Connect connectors with other instances of Kafka.

Comment: Robin, at this point I have running zookeeper on node1, node2, node3. Node1 is a producer, Node2 is a Kafka server and I have running PySpark on Node3 which downloads and retrieves data in the way shown in the question. I have also configured and distributed Hadoop Cluster on these free nodes with HBase. Node1 is the Hbase master. I just need to achieve highest possible performance of streaming and inserting data to Hbase using free tools. Could you show me an example how it could be done?